# Expo Push Notifications : How to send less than 100 push notifications per request?

Tags: node.js, react-native, push-notification, expo

Ive implemented expo push notifications and send notifications to all followers of a product that gets updated on server side with their code:
The node code for sending expo push notifications:
`https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node`

According to expo I would get an error if:

> PUSH_TOO_MANY_NOTIFICATIONS: You are trying to send more than 100 push
> notifications in one request. Make sure you are only sending 100 (or
> fewer) notifications in each request.

How can I limit that if lets say I have 200 followers. How can I send 100 and then send the other 100?
Thanks!